# PHP tipos de arrays e valores

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Como eu transformo esse tipo de dado `$pessoas->nome` para `$pessoas['nome']` e vice-versa com php e porque eles são diferentes?

Comment: Se a explicação longa for plausível, aqui está: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82251/4995

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode altera a tipagem usando `(array)`.

```
$pessoas = new stdClass;
$pessoas->nome = 'Papa Charlie';
$pessoas = (array) $pessoas;


//output: Array( [nome] => Papa Charlie )
print_r( $pessoas );


// output: Papa Charlie
echo $pessoas['nome'];
```

---

O processo inverso, mudando a tipagem usando `(object)`.

```
$pessoas = array( 'nome' => 'Papa Charlie' );
$pessoas = (object) $pessoas;


// output: stdClass Object( [nome] => Papa Charlie )
print_r( $pessoas );


// output: Papa Charlie
echo $pessoas-> nome;
```

Veja um exemplo no [*Ideone*](http://ideone.com/DXQGaJ).

Comment: pode-se também fazer o cast no momento da declaração: 

$pessoas = (object)array( 'nome' => 'Papa Charlie' );

Comment: @DanielOmine, sim, mas acredito que ele precise dos dados como *array*, e somente em algum determinado momento se faz necessário o uso do *object*.

Answer (score 3):

O `$pessoas->nome` indica que pessoas é um objeto. Já `$pessoas['nome']` indica um array. Você pode transformar os nomes presentes em objetos em arrays (desde que eles não sejam estáticos) usando a função `get_object_vars( object $object )`.

Leia mais sobre objetos em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.php

Comment: http://ideone.com/f6NBYL kkk

Comment: ?? @IvanFerrer não entendi a relevância de mostrar o resultado do phpinfo() do Ideone...

Comment: eu havia atualizado a saída para fazer um teste... mas o código era outra coisa que eu havia colocado... olhe novamente.

Comment: certo, mas ainda não entendi qual o seu ponto de vista. Olhe esse aqui: http://ideone.com/MyiLGP

Comment: Não é meu ponto de vista, é apenas uma demonstração de uso do `get_object_vars()`

Comment: ah tá :) perdão

Comment: Se tiver algum ponto de vista, é apenas o humor que já estamos acostumados, para que fazer um método complexo só para dar uma saída de "Olá Mundo".

Comment: Aqui um exemplo disso: http://ideone.com/J3Iilc

Answer (score 2):

Com "setinha" você está referenciando o atributo de um objeto (object), com os colchetes, você está referenciando a chave da matriz (array). Para alternar a tipagem, você teria que forçar a tipagem ou fazer um "cast":

```
class Test {

public $valor = 'teste';

}

$objeto = new Test();

$array['valor'] = 'teste';

/* 1. a variável se torna um array $variavelArray['valor']
   2. O valor do atributo referenciado passará a ser
      tratado como array. */ 
$variavelArray  = (array) $objeto;
/* 1. a variável se torna um objeto $variavelObject->valor
   2. O valor do array passa a ser um atributo uma new StdClass; */
$variavelObject = (object) $array;
```

Aqui tem um exemplo: **http://ideone.com/xgkA7x**

Em muitos casos, é necessário fazer essa conversão, mas tem gente que faz isso como uma *"gambiarra"* para solucionar problemas que poderiam ser tratados de uma forma muito mais elegante.

Answer (score 2):

## Array vs Objetos

Essa "setinha" que há em `$pessoas->nome` se trata do `Object Separator`. Ele é responsável pelo acesso à membros pertencentes a um objeto (seja propriedade ou método).

Nesse primeiro caso `$pessoas->nome`, o `objeto` poderia ser de qualquer classe. No PHP, geralmente, o objeto padrão é o `stdClass`.

Você pode utilizar o `var_dump` nesse caso para saber o nome da classe de onde é oriundo esse objeto.

No caso de `$pessoas['nome']` você está acessando os membros de um `array` no PHP.

Então, veja esse exemplos para poder fixar melhor:

Exemplo de `Array`

```
$array = array('nome' => 'wallace');

echo $array['nome']; // Imprime: 'wallace'
```

Exemplo de `objeto` (stdClass);

```
$object = new stdClass;

$object->nome = 'Wallace';

echo $object->nome; // Imprime: 'wallace';

get_class($object); // Imprime: 'stdClass'
```

## interface ArrayAccess

Existem casos onde você pode usar as duas formas, tanto para objetos como para `arrays`. Isso acontece em qualquer classe que implemente a interface `ArrayAccess`.

O PHP tem por padrão uma classe que implementa `ArrayAccess`, que é o `ArrayObject` (veja que nome mais demonstrativo!)

Veja:

```
$arr_and_obj = new ArrayObject();

$arr_and_obj->nome = 'wallace';

$arr_and_obj['idade'] = 25;

echo $arr_and_obj->nome; // Imprime: 'wallace';

echo $arr_and_obj['idade']; // Imprime: 25
```

Nesse caso, somente classes que implementa essa interface aceita essa "dupla forma de acesso". Em outros casos, um erro será gerado:

Veja:

```
$obj = new stdClass;

$obj[1];
```

Saída:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

## Conversão entre tipos

Como foi citado na resposta do @IvanFerrer, você pode converter esses tipos.

Objeto para `array`:

```
$obj = new stdClass;

$obj->nome = 'wallace';

var_dump((array)$obj);
```

Array para objeto:

```
$obj = (object) array('nome' => 'Wallace');
```

Essas duas formas citadas acima se chama `cast`.

Existe também outra foram de conversão, que é a através da função `settype`.

Veja:

```
$object = new stdClass;

settype($object, 'array');

var_dump($object); // Imprime: Array(0){}
```

Answer (score -4):

Se você usar a classe `PDO` do proprio php terá as opções na hora de fazer uma query por exemplo, podendo usar o:

`PDO::FETCH_OBJ` para objeto, no caso sera retornado e acessara os atributos atraves do `$pessoas->nome` ou usando o `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`
retorna em forma de array como `$pessoas['nome']`.

Segue o [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: *Nenhum* elemento na questão sugere banco de dados! Toda alternativa é bem vinda, tanto para a comunidade e para o *AP*, mas desde que esteja no escopo da pergunta.